# Looking for a list of available column filter commands [Me] [Today] [etc.... ]

Tags: filter

I am looking for a list of commands that can be used in column filters

I know only a few commands but I think there must be a lot more of them.
But since I'm not sure how they are called, I cannot search for it.

So does anybody know where to look or have a list of them?

I see Microsoft using examples such as 
**Last Updated is greater than [Today]-30**

From this site

[Manage lists and libraries in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016](http://support.office.microsoft.com/client/HA102771361?lcid=1033&query=&NS=&Version=&ShowNav=false&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&app=&msg=&origin=&ocmsassetID=HA102771361&helpid=filtering#_Toc346115851)

I see they are using some commands and I'd like to know if there is a place where i can find full set of commands

Comment: [Me] and [Today] are the only dynamic filters available for list views.

Answer (score 2):

`[Me]` and `[Today]` are the only dynamic filters available for list views.

`[Me]` works when trying to dynamically filter on person/group fields based on the current user.

`[Today]` works when trying to dynamically filter on date fields based on the current date.

Answer (score 0):

The OOTB parameters list is pretty small. You can create your own parameters if needed using SharePoint Designer. This will get you started. http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/01/sharepoint-2010-passing-parameter-values-into-listitem-forms/

Answer (score -1):

These are few commands which can be used for a SharePoint calculated column in the list. Probably, the same can be used for applying filters because i have used same [Today] or [Me] in the filter which i have used for Calculated columns as well. Check which will suit you requirement.

Get Week of the year

```
=DATE(YEAR([Start Time]),MONTH([Start Time]),DAY([Start Time]))+0.5-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([Start Time]),MONTH([Start Time]),DAY([Start Time])),2)+1
```

First day of the week for a given date:

```
=[Start Date]-WEEKDAY([Start Date])+1
```

Last day of the week for a given date:

```
=[End Date]+7-WEEKDAY([End Date])
```

First day of the month for a given date:

```
=DATEVALUE(“1/”&MONTH([Start Date])&”/”&YEAR([Start Date]))
```

Last day of the month for a given year (does not handle Feb 29). Result is in date format:

```
=DATEVALUE (CHOOSE(MONTH([End Date]),31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31) &”/” & MONTH([End Date])&”/”&YEAR([End Date]))
Day Name of the week : e.g Monday, Mon
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Start Date]), “dddd”)
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Start Date]), “ddd”)
```

The name of the month for a given date – numbered for sorting – e.g. 01. January:

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH([Date Created]),”01. January”, “02. February”, “03. March”, “04. April”, “05. May” , “06. June” , “07. July” , “08. August” , “09. September” , “10. October” , “11. November” , “12. December”)
```

Get Hours difference between two Date-Time :

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([End Time])),([End Time]-[Start Time])*24,0)
```

Date Difference in days – Hours – Min format : e.g 4days 5hours 10min :

```
=YEAR(Today)-YEAR(Created)-IF(OR(MONTH(Today)<MONTH(Created),AND(MONTH(Today)=MONTH(Created),
DAY(Today)<DAY(Created))),1,0)&” years, “&MONTH(Today)-MONTH(Created)+IF(AND(MONTH(Today)
<=MONTH(Created),DAY(Today)<DAY(Created)),11,IF(AND(MONTH(Today)<MONTH(Created),DAY(Today)
>=DAY(Created)),12,IF(AND(MONTH(Today)>MONTH(Created),DAY(Today)<DAY(Created)),-1)))&” months,
“&Today-DATE(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today)-IF(DAY(Today)<DAY(Created),1,0),DAY(Created))&” days”
```